# How to make combine Gregorian and Hijri calendar in Android?

Tags: android, calendar

I need a combined Gregorian and Hijri calendar, I found this Hijri calendar on [github](https://github.com/eltohamy/material-hijri-calendarview), and it helpful for me, but i couldn't show Gregorian type on it. my question is: should I modify on source code of it, or should I custom Android calendar view widget? 
If should I custom on Android calendar view widget, how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by learn a concept of calendar view, it is easy to learn from this [topic](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want) read it carefully.
Once you learned how to build a custom calendar, then you should build your own one.